# nx with vite builds a lib with peer dependencies (react, react-dom)

Tags: reactjs, vite, peer-dependencies

I've a standard installation: nx with vite as bundler. I have a main app and a library. Both uses react. Also a library can be used independenly. I'm trying to build library with a command:

```
nx build --production <library-name>
```

but I see that react and react-dom exist in the built bundle.
There are two package.json files: root and library. In both files react and react-dom are set as peerDependencies.

At the beginning react and react-dom were devDependencies. By the way, the were packed into production build. I moved them into peerDependencies. It didn't help, they are still packed into production build.

How to explain vite that they should not be included into production bundle for my library?

Answer (score 3):

I think I've found a solution. The problem was in vite.config.js.
At the beginning I added "react" and "react-dom" into rollupOptions.external:

```
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["react", "react-dom"],
    }
  }
})
```

After that react and react-dom were excluded from production build, but other react-libraries on which react depends were still there.

Then I found another solution - rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external:

```
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    ...
  ]
})
```

It helped. Now production build for a library doesn't contain react or react-dom or its dependencies